# como mudar a cor em cada selectitem de um selectOneRadio jsf

Tags: css, jsf

tenho um selectOneRadio que tem 3 opções : Acabamento, embargo e Expedição

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{solicitacaoImpressaoBean.entrega.tipoGuia}" class="tipoGuia" >
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="Acabamento" itemLabel="Acabamento" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="Embargo" itemLabel="Embargo" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="Expedicao" itemLabel="Expedição"/>
    </h:selectOneRadio>
```

Quero colocar no primeiro a cor preto, no segundo a cor azul e no terceiro a cor verde.

tentei com css a seguinte maneira:

```
.tipoGuia tr:nth-child(1) td label   {
    color : black
 }
.tipoGuia tr:nth-child(2) td label   {
   color : blue
} 
.tipoGuia tr:nth-child(3) td label   {
   color : green;

}
```

mas não funcionou. alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso? grato.

Consegui assim:

```
.tipoGuia tr td:nth-of-type(1){
    color : black;
}
.tipoGuia tr td:nth-of-type(2){
    color : blue;
}
.tipoGuia tr td:nth-of-type(3){
    color : green;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui assim:

```
.tipoGuia tr td:nth-of-type(1){
    color : black;
}
.tipoGuia tr td:nth-of-type(2){
    color : blue;
}
.tipoGuia tr td:nth-of-type(3){
    color : green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando precisei fazer algo parecido fiz da seguinte forma:

peguei o seu código como exemplo, para testá-lo aqui, usei styleClass, mas pode usar somente class também

```
<h:selectOneRadio styleClass="tipoGuia">
             <f:selectItem itemValue="Acabamento" itemLabel="Acabamento"/>
             <f:selectItem itemValue="Embargo" itemLabel="Embargo" />
             <f:selectItem itemValue="Expedicao" itemLabel="Expedição"  >
             </f:selectItem>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

O que você precisa fazer é pegar o valor definido no itemValue e levar para o css, da seguinte forma:

```
.tipoGuia 
    input[value="Acabamento"] + label {color:black} 
.tipoGuia
    input[value="Embargo"] + label {color:blue}
.tipoGuia
    input[value="Expedicao"] + label {color:green}
```

Se você observar, quando inspecionamos os itens do select no navegador, ele sempre nos mostra um

```
<label for="enderecoDoSeuObjeto">Acabamento</label>
```

com os dados de cada item inspecionado.

Comment: Consegui assim:

    .tipoGuia tr td:nth-of-type(1){
     color : black;
    }
    .tipoGuia tr td:nth-of-type(2){
     color : blue;
    }
    .tipoGuia tr td:nth-of-type(3){
        color : green;
    }